# What's the meaning of these kanji in this image still?

Tags: kanji

This is a sincere question, I apologize for the lewdeness, though.

I was watching a japanese pornographic film and I stumbled upon this written phrase. I wanted to know what it means (I'm also starting to study japanese -not related to the porn, lol-). I attach just the sign so you don't have to watch the video:

[image]

I am able to read hiragana but I can't discern the kanji.

Thanks in advance and again I apologize.

Comment: Please don't attach links to pornographic websites.

Comment: So.. two users have provided the *literal* meaning of that word/phrase so far... Does it make sense in your context? If not... I'm not sure if I'm allowed to say its non-literal meaning here..

Comment: I think it's clear from the context.

Comment: ^ そうなんですか・・　「たまってる」は、「欲求不満の状態」とか「性欲が満たされてない」ことを言う俗語ですけど、"Do you have a lot of ... stored up?" "collect/accumulate" って言えば、文脈でわかるんですか。。。

Comment: We usually don't do translation or character recognition here, please have a look https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. Jisho.org can surely help you for this kind of question, you could use the drawing function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

溜まってるの？　＝　たまっていますか。

Do you have a lot of ... stored up?

Answer (score 0):

It is 溜まる(たまる): collect, accumulate
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/溜まる/#je-46705](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E6%BA%9C%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8B/#je-46705)
https://kakijun.jp/page/ryuu13200.html